# bypassing TAB auto-complete

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-you-complete-me, tab-characters, plugin-supertab

Sometimes I need to press <kbd>TAB</kbd>, but instead of getting actual the tab key, a suggestion pops up and <kbd>TAB</kbd> cycles through the suggestions.

How can I insert <kbd>TAB</kbd> without invoking the auto-completion ?

The problem occurrs both in YouCompleteMe and SuperTab plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use a different key mapping for completion instead of hijacking the Tab key. Having one key to preform two actions and "guess" which one it should do is just a misguided approach IMHO.

For SuperTab see `:help supertab-forwardbackward`:

```
g:SuperTabMappingForward  (default value: '<tab>')
g:SuperTabMappingBackward (default value: '<s-tab>')

These two variables allow you to set the keys used to kick off the current
completion. By default this is <tab> and <s-tab>. To change to something
like <c-space> and <s-c-space>, you can add the following to your |vimrc|.

    let g:SuperTabMappingForward = '<c-space>'
    let g:SuperTabMappingBackward = '<s-c-space>'
```

And for YouCompleteMe see `:help g:ycm_key_list_select_completion`:

```
The *g:ycm_key_list_select_completion* option

This option controls the key mappings used to select the first completion
string. Invoking any of them repeatedly cycles forward through the completion
list.

Some users like adding '<Enter>' to this list.

Default: "['<TAB>', '<Down>']"

    let g:ycm_key_list_select_completion = ['<TAB>', '<Down>']
```

---

Another alternative is mapping another key combination to `<Tab>`; e.g.:

```
inorenap <Leader><Tab> <Tab>
```

And then use `\<Tab>` to get the default tab behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

You can always bypass the effects of a keypress by preceding it with a <kbd>ctrl-v</kbd>. For example, if you'd like to insert a literal escape character without returning to normal mode, you can do from insert mode:

```
<C-v><esc>
```

This also works on the command line. I don't have YouCompleteMe, or SuperTab installed so I haven't tested this solution, but it should work fine to do

```
<C-v><tab>
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: I have SuperTab installed, and `<c-v><tab>` works.